# Hover over one div, effect the opacity of an image in another div (with jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, opacity

I'm working on this website: http://users.telenet.be/blijvendvertrek/default.htm.

Now I want to establish that when I hover over one of three navigation items, ('Renovaties', 'Gerechtelijke expertise' or 'Over mij') located in a , the corresponding image in the  right below it changes its opacity (from 0.6 to 1.0).

Via CSS, I have already established that each of those three images changes its opacity if you hover over it directly, but I can't seem to generate the same effect when I hover over the navigation items. I've inserted a script to achieve this effect, but it doesn't work.

This is the html for one of the three navigation items:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
    <li id="1"><a href="renovaties/renovaties.htm" title="Renovaties">RENOVATIES</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

This is the html for the corresponding content item:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="kolom links">
       <a href="renovaties/renovaties.htm" title="Renovaties">
                        <img src="images/Icoon - Renovaties.png" alt="Renovaties" id="img-1"/></a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the script I can't get to work:

```
$("#img-1, #img-2, #img-3").css('opacity','0.6');

$("#1").hover(function () {
    $('#img-1').css({opacity : 1.0});
  }, 
  function () {
    $('#img-1').css({opacity : 0.6});
  }
);

$("#2").hover(function () {
    $('#img-2').css({opacity : 1.0});
  }, 
  function () {
    $('#img-2').css({opacity : 0.6});
  }
);

$("#3").hover(function () {
    $('#img-3').css({opacity : 1.0});
  }, 
  function () {
    $('#img-3').css({opacity : 0.6});
  }
);
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thank you all very much.

Comment: I can't see that you included jQuery on your page?

Comment: Check this fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/DTvGC/
It seems like if you add jQuery 2.0 then it won't work but it is working with 1.9.1.

Comment: Dear vijay, thank you, it Looks just how I want it to  in your fiddle - but using the same script, I can't get my website to do the same (see http://users.telenet.be/blijvendvertrek/default.htm). It's just as if my web site doesn't pick up on the script... Any idea on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Dear vijay, just nuw I saw that in your fiddle, the images don't take on the 1.0 opacity as you hover over them. I wanted to ensure that as well.

Comment: Dear all, I got it to work! I stupidly forgot linking my html document to a source file for the script. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

DEMO:   http://jsfiddle.net/Xc6ug/2/

Better To use mouseenter and mouseleave instead of hover like this

```
$("#1").mouseenter(function () {
$('#img-1').css({"opacity","1"});
});

$("#1").mouseleave(function () {
$('#img-1').css({"opacity", "0.6"});
});
```

Comment: `hover` is simply a combination of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Dear Arun, I've changed my script, but Dreamweaver indicates there's a syntax error in this line: $('#img-1').css({"opacity", "1"}); - hence, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hello Praveen.J - thanks, I no longer get the syntax error warning, but I still don't get the desired effect on my page :-(

Comment: Check this fiddle... jsfiddle.net/DTvGC It seems like if you add jQuery 2.0 then it won't work but it is working with 1.9.1.  Check VIAY's fiddle.. i think that would help u..

Comment: Dear all, I swiched to 1.9.1, but to no avail... What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: @user2367451: kindly use this line before your <script> tag. <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>; beause your are not included jquery in your code so it wont take desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

id cannot be only numeric in html < 5

as your li are in order, you can use .index()

```
$("#navigation li").hover(function(){
    var n = $(this).index()+1;
    $('#img-'+n).css({opacity:1});
},function(){
    var n = $(this).index()+1;
    $('#img-'+n).css({opacity:0.6});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you do this code

```
$("#img-1, #img-2, #img-3").css('opacity','0.6');
```

Try setting the opacity instead in a css file or as a inline style when the page loads.
Just encase this code is continuously resetting any changes you make on the fly.

Just an idea.

Comment: Ah sorry my friend. Try
`code`alert("Mouse entered")`code` on you navigational divs just to see if the hover event is actually firing